# python uses incorrect path

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I have bash script which runs Python program. I use virtualenv.

Firs I include env to bash:

```
source ./ENV/bin/activate
```

Then I see (ENV) prefix in bash prompt.

```
$ echo $PATH
/project/ENV/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

When I try to run my Python program from bash script, it runs with wrong version of Python. ENV uses Python 2.6, while the system has 3.2 by default.

I print Python version from Python script, and it prints 3.

But why?

```
ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 2219 Sep 27 01:42 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 1275 Sep 27 01:42 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 2414 Sep 27 01:42 activate.fish
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 1129 Sep 27 01:42 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc 357 Sep 27 01:42 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc 365 Sep 27 01:42 easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc 318 Sep 27 01:42 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc 326 Sep 27 01:42 pip-2.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wnc wnc 9 Sep 27 01:42 python -> python2.6 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wnc wnc 9 Sep 27 01:42 python2 -> python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc 6240 Sep 27 01:42 python2.6
```

Comment: What is the result of `which python`?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -la /project/ENV/bin`?

Comment: [code]

ls -la


-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 2219 Sep 27 01:42 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 1275 Sep 27 01:42 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 2414 Sep 27 01:42 activate.fish
-rw-r--r-- 1 wnc wnc 1129 Sep 27 01:42 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc  357 Sep 27 01:42 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc  365 Sep 27 01:42 easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc  318 Sep 27 01:42 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc  326 Sep 27 01:42 pip-2.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wnc wnc    9 Sep 27 01:42 python -> python2.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wnc wnc    9 Sep 27 01:42 python2 -> python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnc wnc 6240 Sep 27 01:42 python2.6

[code]

Comment: It's not very readable when you post that as a Comment. Can you add it to your Answer. Also, what's the output of `python -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.version_info)'`.

Comment: in the interpreter which python returns env/bin python


in the bash script I run user /usr/bin/python

Comment: Maybe you are running the script as a different user? What's the line that runs the Python script in Bash script?

Comment: How are you executing your Python application? It seems that it's not executing the right Python instance indeed. If `which python` is correct and the listing of your bin directory looks good, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sanity check:

```
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
python -V
deactivate
python -V
```

The first `python -V` should show print `Python 2.6` and the second `Python 3.2`, right?

When you run your Python script, the one you want to use the above virtualenv, make sure to source `/path/to/ENV/bin/activate` first, for example if you run it from inside a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
python /path/to/script.py
```

Tell me which step doesn't work and any error messages you get.

If your python program needs to run in a different way, not from a shell script, for example by wsgi, then I'll have more tips for you. The bottom line is: don't forget to source the virtualenv activate script before using your python script that needs it.